# Swift-4 MacOS Detect Mouse Wheel Scroll over NSTextField?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, mousewheel

I have a NSTextField on a MacOS app with Swift-4

Its purpose is for the user to input a number.
Is there a way to change the number based on scroll up or scroll down of a mouse wheel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just override `scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent)` method and check if the `event.deltaY` is positive or negative and increase or decrease the textField value:

```
import Cocoa
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.stringValue = "0"
    }
    override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.scrollWheel(with: event)
        if var value = Int(textField.stringValue) {
            if event.deltaY > 0 { value += 1 }
            if event.deltaY < 0 { value -= 1 }
            textField.stringValue = String(value)
            print(value)
        }
    }
}
```

If you would like to just change the field that has focus you can use the view window fieldEditor:

```
if let text = view.window?.fieldEditor(false, for: nil) {
    if var value = Int(text.string) {
        if event.deltaY > 0 { value += 1 }
        if event.deltaY < 0 { value -= 1 }
        text.string = String(value)
        print(value)
    }
}
```

If you would like to restrict the scroll to just a particular field you would need to set your view controller as the delegate of it and compare its delegate against the textfield object:

```
import Cocoa
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField1: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField2: NSTextField!
    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()
        textField1.delegate = self
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField1.stringValue = "0"
        textField2.stringValue = "0"
    }
    override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.scrollWheel(with: event)
        NSSound(named: "Tink")?.stop
        if view.window?.firstResponder?.textView?.delegate === textField1,
            let text = view.window?.fieldEditor(false, for: nil),
            var value = Int(text.string) {
            if event.deltaY < 0 { value += 1 }
            if event.deltaY > 0 { value -= 1 }
            NSSound(named: "Tink")?.play()
            text.string = String(value)
            print(value)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
extension NSResponder {
    var textView: NSTextView? { return self as? NSTextView }
}
```

Comment: That was incredible fast and helpful and accurate. Much respects! I tried and it works. Only problem is that it changes the value no matter if the textfield is on focus or not. Is there a way to limit this effect only when the textfield has focus?

Comment: You can check the delegate. It is kind of tricky but I can show you

Comment: I looked around for an answer, but most of it is on ObjC and they talk about subclassing and stuff. On C world there is something like a bool property like hasFocus and iOS it has isFirstResponder or something like that. But here seems pretty complex. Any help would be super appreciated.

Comment: Incredible you are in another level man. Thank you so so so so much!!